# SQLite3 Virtual Tables and Not Null

Tags: sqlite

I appear to be having a problem with Virtual Tables in SQLite3.

Create Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Test1 (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, Value TEXT);
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE Test2 USING fts4 (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, Value TEXT);
```

As you can see they are essentially identical except one is Virtual for FTS4 support.

```
INSERT INTO Test1 (Value) values("test");
INSERT INTO Test2 (Value) values("test");
```

Results for Test1:

```
id          Value
```

`----------  ----------`

```
1           test
```

Results for Test2:

```
id          Value
```

`----------  ----------`

```
            test
```

Is there a way to get SQLite3 to force the NOT NULL characteristic for Virtual Tables?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can use the `rowid` column, which is available in both standard and virtual SQLite tables, to achieve what you want.

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE Test2 USING fts4 (Value TEXT);
```

When you want to insert a new record, just pass `null` as the value of the `rowid`:

```
INSERT INTO Test2(rowid, Value) VALUES(null, 'hello');
```

The default behavior in SQLite for assigning the `rowid` when the insert value is `null` is to increment the previous largest value by 1.  This will behave similarly to what you had in mind when using `AUTOINCREMENT`.

To obtain the `rowid` in a query on your table, you can try something like this:

```
SELECT rowid, * FROM Test2;
```

Here is a [link to the SQLite documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) which discusses the behavior of `null` with `rowid`.  And [here is a link](https://sqlite.org/fts3.htmlttp://) which mentions that FTS tables do have a `rowid` column like regular tables.

Answer (score 0):

Virtual tables are not implemented by SQLite itself but by some separate piece of code.

The FTS module does not support data types or constraints; its virtual tables have only plain text columns, and all columns (including your `id` column) are indexed for full-text searches.

As shown in the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#section_1_3), FTS tables have an implicit INTEGER PRIMARY KEY column which can be accessed as `docid` or `rowid`.